# Flutter - parse json data into list

Tags: android, json, flutter

I am new in flutter, I had to parse the same JSON response in Android but I don't know to parse JSON in Flutter. As, I am able to print responses in console, But don't know to create a model class.

Below is the function where I can get and print the JSON response.

```
Future<Null> getHomeData() async {
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});

final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(APIs.url_HomePage));
Map responseMap = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

var adv_img = responseMap['adv_img'] as List;
var info_text = responseMap['info_text'] as List;
var shop_cat = responseMap['shop_cat'] as List;
var section = responseMap['section'] as List;

print(adv_img);
print(info_text);
print(shop_cat);
print(section);


setState(() {
  loading = false;
  });
}
```

[Here is the link for the JSON file](https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/c5f596fa0c03ed9f8a27e8ca0b2c33b7) and [link for Model Class](https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/f6af0e376d168e398ac11e43af49be7d)

Please help me solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example that I have created based on you json data:

json file:

```
{
    "adv_img": [
      {
        "category_id": "666",
        "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/ikol/home/banner.jpg?v=6.71",
        "tag": "category"
      }
    ],
    "info_text": [
      {
        "text_head": "FREE DELIVERY AND INSTALLATION",
        "text_sub": " Across All Major Cities"
      },
      {
        "text_head": "GET EXTRA 20% OFF ON ALL PRODUCTS",
        "text_sub": "Use Coupon Code INDIA20"
      },
      {
        "text_head": "LARGE EXPERIENCE STORE NETWORK",
        "text_sub": "20+ Stores Across India"
      }
    ],
    "shop_cat": [
      {
        "category_id": "landing",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/popular-sofas.jpg",
        "category_name": "prodcut_1"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "landing",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/popular-bed.jpg",
        "category_name": "prodcut_2"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "17",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/shop-8.jpg",
        "category_name": "TV prodcut_3"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "29",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/popular-stud.jpg",
        "category_name": "prodcut_4"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "13",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/popular-bed.jpg",
        "category_name": "prodcut_5"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "landing",
        "icon_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/popular.jpg",
        "category_name": "prodcut_6"
      }
    ],
    "section": [
      {
        "banner": [
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "666",
            "category_name": "banner_1",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/-store.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "55",
            "category_name": "banner_2",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/beds.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "13",
            "category_name": "banner_3",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/beds.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "top_selling": {
          "tag": "Top Selling Products",
          "view_type": 0,
          "traget": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "product_id": "3842",
              "category_id": "56",
              "name": "top_1",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/size.jpg?",
              "price": "₹ 77,999",
              "special": "₹ 42,499",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "8581",
              "category_id": "299",
              "name": "top_2",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/sofa.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 51,099",
              "special": "₹ 29,989",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "1"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "19767",
              "category_id": "545",
              "name": "top_3",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/seater.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 68,999",
              "special": "₹ 41,999",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "1"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "17914",
              "category_id": "25",
              "name": "top_4",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/tables.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 34,999",
              "special": "₹ 19,898",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "19476",
              "category_id": "36",
              "name": "top_5",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/chairs.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 32,999",
              "special": "₹ 18,999",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "15657",
              "category_id": "116",
              "name": "top_6",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/divans.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 49,599",
              "special": "₹ 29,989",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "6190",
              "category_id": "56",
              "name": "top_7",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/walken-bed.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 79,999",
              "special": "₹ 42,799",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "16360",
              "category_id": "29",
              "name": "top_8",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/study-table-top.jpg?v=4",
              "price": "₹ 44,999",
              "special": "₹ 24,989",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "18377",
              "category_id": "22",
              "name": "top_9",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/bookshelves.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 33,699 ",
              "special": "₹ 18,499",
              "discount": "null",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "1929",
              "category_id": "101",
              "name": "top_09",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/drawer.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 37,499",
              "special": "₹ 21,849",
              "discount": "null",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "shop_by": {
          "tag": "Shop By Room",
          "view_type": 1,
          "traget": 0,
          "data": [
            [
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "628",
                "name": "room_1",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-1.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "3",
                "name": "- room_2",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-2.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "2",
                "name": "- room_3",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-3.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "28",
                "name": "- room_4",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-4.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "155",
                "name": "- room_6",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-5.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "4",
                "name": "- room_5 ",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/images/aui87/shopby-6.jpg",
                "price": "",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "banner": [
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "36",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_1",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/loungechair.png"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "141",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_2",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/diningset.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "134",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_3",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/coffeetable.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_4",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/makeinindia.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "29",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_5",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/study.jpg"
          },
          {
            "tag": "category",
            "category_id": "7",
            "screen": 0,
            "category_name": "banner_6",
            "banner_image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/homedecor.png"
          }
        ],
        "top_selling": {
          "tag": "Designs For You",
          "view_type": 0,
          "traget": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "product_id": "24748",
              "category_id": "29",
              "name": "selling_1",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/-table.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 25,899",
              "special": "₹ 15,999 ",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "24679",
              "category_id": "17",
              "name": "selling_2",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/hatv-unit.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 22,899",
              "special": "₹ 13,499",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "24747",
              "category_id": "19",
              "name": "selling_3",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/-rack.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 16,899",
              "special": "₹ 10,499 ",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "24733",
              "category_id": "25",
              "name": "selling_4",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/ee-table.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 19,899",
              "special": "₹ 11,999",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            },
            {
              "product_id": "24736",
              "category_id": "91",
              "name": "selling_5",
              "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/2-door-.jpg",
              "price": "₹ 33,899",
              "special": "₹ 16,499",
              "discount": "",
              "fabricConcept": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "shop_by": {
          "tag": "For Your Home ",
          "view_type": 0,
          "traget": 0,
          "data": [
            [
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "151",
                "name": "shop_by_1",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/beds.jpg",
                "price": "From ₹ 24,899",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "43",
                "name": "shop_by_2",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/stools.jpg",
                "price": "From ₹ 7,999 ",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "548",
                "name": "shop_by_3",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/mattress.jpg",
                "price": "From ₹ 9,499 ",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "91",
                "name": "shop_by_4",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/two.jpg",
                "price": "From ₹ 14,899 ",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "12",
                "name": "shop_by_5",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/sofa.jpg",
                "price": "From ₹ 14,879 ",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              },
              {
                "product_id": "",
                "category_id": "53",
                "name": "shop_by_6",
                "image": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/units.jpg?v=3",
                "price": "From ₹ 14,879 ",
                "special": "",
                "discount": "",
                "fabricConcept": "0"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "_img": "localhost://example.com/mobile/images-m/aui87/all.jpg?v=3"
  }
```

model class data:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final home = homeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Home homeFromJson(String str) => Home.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String homeToJson(Home data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Home {
    Home({
        this.advImg,
        this.infoText,
        this.shopCat,
        this.section,
        this.img,
    });

    List<AdvImg> advImg;
    List<InfoText> infoText;
    List<ShopCat> shopCat;
    List<Section> section;
    String img;

    factory Home.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Home(
        advImg: List<AdvImg>.from(json["adv_img"].map((x) => AdvImg.fromJson(x))),
        infoText: List<InfoText>.from(json["info_text"].map((x) => InfoText.fromJson(x))),
        shopCat: List<ShopCat>.from(json["shop_cat"].map((x) => ShopCat.fromJson(x))),
        section: List<Section>.from(json["section"].map((x) => Section.fromJson(x))),
        img: json["_img"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "adv_img": List<dynamic>.from(advImg.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "info_text": List<dynamic>.from(infoText.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "shop_cat": List<dynamic>.from(shopCat.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "section": List<dynamic>.from(section.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "_img": img,
    };
}

class AdvImg {
    AdvImg({
        this.categoryId,
        this.image,
        this.tag,
    });

    String categoryId;
    String image;
    String tag;

    factory AdvImg.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AdvImg(
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        image: json["image"],
        tag: json["tag"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "image": image,
        "tag": tag,
    };
}

class InfoText {
    InfoText({
        this.textHead,
        this.textSub,
    });

    String textHead;
    String textSub;

    factory InfoText.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => InfoText(
        textHead: json["text_head"],
        textSub: json["text_sub"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "text_head": textHead,
        "text_sub": textSub,
    };
}

class Section {
    Section({
        this.banner,
        this.topSelling,
        this.shopBy,
    });

    List<Banner> banner;
    TopSelling topSelling;
    ShopBy shopBy;

    factory Section.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Section(
        banner: List<Banner>.from(json["banner"].map((x) => Banner.fromJson(x))),
        topSelling: TopSelling.fromJson(json["top_selling"]),
        shopBy: ShopBy.fromJson(json["shop_by"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "banner": List<dynamic>.from(banner.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "top_selling": topSelling.toJson(),
        "shop_by": shopBy.toJson(),
    };
}

class Banner {
    Banner({
        this.tag,
        this.categoryId,
        this.categoryName,
        this.bannerImage,
        this.screen,
    });

    String tag;
    String categoryId;
    String categoryName;
    String bannerImage;
    int screen;

    factory Banner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Banner(
        tag: json["tag"],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        bannerImage: json["banner_image"],
        screen: json["screen"] == null ? null : json["screen"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tag": tag,
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "category_name": categoryName,
        "banner_image": bannerImage,
        "screen": screen == null ? null : screen,
    };
}

class ShopBy {
    ShopBy({
        this.tag,
        this.viewType,
        this.traget,
        this.data,
    });

    String tag;
    int viewType;
    int traget;
    List<List<Datum>> data;

    factory ShopBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ShopBy(
        tag: json["tag"],
        viewType: json["view_type"],
        traget: json["traget"],
        data: List<List<Datum>>.from(json["data"].map((x) => List<Datum>.from(x.map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tag": tag,
        "view_type": viewType,
        "traget": traget,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x.toJson())))),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.productId,
        this.categoryId,
        this.name,
        this.image,
        this.price,
        this.special,
        this.discount,
        this.fabricConcept,
    });

    String productId;
    String categoryId;
    String name;
    String image;
    String price;
    String special;
    Discount discount;
    String fabricConcept;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        productId: json["product_id"],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        image: json["image"],
        price: json["price"],
        special: json["special"],
        discount: discountValues.map[json["discount"]],
        fabricConcept: json["fabricConcept"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "product_id": productId,
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "name": name,
        "image": image,
        "price": price,
        "special": special,
        "discount": discountValues.reverse[discount],
        "fabricConcept": fabricConcept,
    };
}

enum Discount { EMPTY, NULL }

final discountValues = EnumValues({
    "": Discount.EMPTY,
    "null": Discount.NULL
});

class TopSelling {
    TopSelling({
        this.tag,
        this.viewType,
        this.traget,
        this.data,
    });

    String tag;
    int viewType;
    int traget;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory TopSelling.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TopSelling(
        tag: json["tag"],
        viewType: json["view_type"],
        traget: json["traget"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tag": tag,
        "view_type": viewType,
        "traget": traget,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class ShopCat {
    ShopCat({
        this.categoryId,
        this.iconImage,
        this.categoryName,
    });

    String categoryId;
    String iconImage;
    String categoryName;

    factory ShopCat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ShopCat(
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        iconImage: json["icon_image"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "icon_image": iconImage,
        "category_name": categoryName,
    };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
    Map<T, String> reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
}
```

main ui file :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/model2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  List<AdvImg> advImgList = List();
  List<InfoText> infoTextList = List();
  List<ShopCat> shopCatList = List();
  List<Section> sectionList = List();

  bool _isLoading = false;

  fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    // This is the above where you get the remote data
    // Like var response = await http.get('your url');
    // final home = homeFromJson(response.body);

    final home = homeFromJson(data);

    advImgList = home.advImg;
    infoTextList = home.infoText;
    shopCatList = home.shopCat;
    sectionList = home.section;

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your heading'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: _isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: advImgList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Text(
                              ' Adv Image List Category Id : ${advImgList[index].categoryId}'),
                        );
                      }),
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: infoTextList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Text(
                              ' Text List : ${infoTextList[index].textSub}'),
                        );
                      }),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check out and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this which has worked for me.

```
List<YourModel> sampleModel;
var response = await http.get("YourUrl");

sampleModel=(json.decode(response.body) as List).map((i) =>
              YourModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
```